# How to use DIN FF font in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, latex, osx-mavericks, xelatex, fontspec

I am trying to use DIN FF font in LaTeX with the fontspec package.

The font is installed in OSX:
[image]

In LaTeX I tried:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DIN}
\setmainfont{DIN FF}
\setmainfont{DIN Regular}
...
```

Nothing seems to work. With `DIN` alone it goes in an infinite loop, with the other combinations it simply does not find the font.

Comment: Hello! This question seems to fit better to tex.SE, so I've flagged it for migration. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain LaTeX can't make use of the `fontspec` package. You need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for that.

If you are already using XeLaTeX (not obvious, but it is in your tags), then you have to make sure that you use the right font name and that the font cache is updated.

For the cache, use `fc-cache`. To get the list of fonts with their correct names, use `fc-list`.

If all of that fails, you can resort to using LuaLaTeX or telling XeLaTeX what you want exactly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[path=/my/dir/fonts]{DINFF.ttf}

\begin{document}
    Blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could not find `fc-cache` and `fc-list` tools. However, it worked by specifying the path (I had to add a `/` at the end). Thanks.

Comment: If these tools are not available, feel free to search for mac-specific alternatives: if the path declaration is working this is great but it's much more convenient just to type the font name. But well, it's already working :)